# Find rows in DataFrame that have duplicates in two columns

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

The DataFrame is given as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,9,2,9,6], 'col2' : [13,4,5,4,5,0], 'col3' : [8,23,5,4,9,5]})
   col1 col2 col3
0   1   13   8
1   2   4    23
2   9   5    5
3   2   4    4
4   9   5    9
5   6   0    5
```

How can I filter this DataFrame, so that I get only the rows that have the duplicates in both col1 and col2.
So eventually the DataFrame should look like this:

```
df_new
   col1 col2 col3
0   2    4    23
1   2    4    5
2   9    5    4
3   9    5    9
```

Comment: In your `df_new` you provided, the rows don't have the same value in both col1 and col3 - can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: In the first df, row 1 and row 3 have the same values in col1 and col2 (2,4). Also, rows 2 and rows 4 share the same values (9,5). Do you know what I mean?

Comment: So you want to keep the rows that have duplicated values in both col1 and col2?

Comment: Yes, and both of them (because col3 is different).

Comment: How can I filter this DataFrame, so that I get only the rows that have the same value in both col1 and col2 so it measn col1 == col2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```py
df_new = df[df.duplicated(subset=["col1", "col2"], keep=False)]
```